# Retain Project Structure[element order] while writing pom file using MavenXpp3Writer

Tags: git, maven

In my usecase I need to update values certain project properties in pom file, at run time.
Hence the code  I use is like this.

```
MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
pomStream = new FileInputStream(pomF);
Model model = reader.read(pomStream);

       // update properties 

  model.setProperties(modelProperties);
  MavenXpp3Writer writer = new MavenXpp3Writer();
  writer.write(new FileWriter(pomF), model);
```

When I do this the elements of pom file are completely re arranged. I need to retain the structure and simply update properties as I need to perform git commit of changed file.

Is there a way to achieve this.?

Comment: What would you like to do? Which properties woud you like to update? dependencies etc. ?

Comment: MavenXpp3Writer rearranges your pom, but it does so consistently. Would it be an option to accept the rearraging once (without changing the properties, just read and write)? After that your changes in git would always be only the real changes?

Comment: @khmarbaise : I would like to change user properties.

Comment: @blackbuild : Yeah checked that It performs the changes consistently. It will be a workaround to accept the rearrangement once, which is what I am doing right now. But I was wondering if there is a way to configure MavenXpp3Writer to perform the write in place.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that properties are read inside a `java.util.Properties` and because it is based on a hashtable, the ordering of the particular property when writing the file is not the "read first order" but the determined by iteraton of the hashtable's hash values, which is deterministic but most probably is not the order defined in the xml file.

As a workaround, class `MavenXpp3ReaderEx` maintains the `InputLocation` of what it reads from the xml file: it saves line number and column number of the tag.

This groovy script shows how to use line numbers to force write the properties in the same order of the original pom.xml file (a java version of this script should be easy to adapt):

```
import org.apache.maven.model.Model;
import org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.*;

@Grapes(
  @Grab(group='org.apache.maven', module='maven-model', version='3.3.9')
)

def f = new File(args[0]);
def reader = new MavenXpp3ReaderEx();
def model = reader.read(f.newInputStream(), true, null);

// your modifications
model.getProperties().put("plexusVersion","99.99");

// reorder properties keys by line number
def locations = model.getLocation( "properties" );

def mapByLine = new TreeMap();

model.getProperties().each { key, val ->
  def loc = locations.getLocation(key);
  mapByLine.put(loc.getLineNumber(), key);
}

def newProps = new Properties() {
  public Set keySet() {
    return new LinkedHashSet(mapByLine.values());
  }
}

newProps.putAll(model.getProperties());

model.setProperties(newProps);

def writer = new MavenXpp3Writer();
def fout = new File("output-pom.xml");
writer.write(fout.newOutputStream(), model);
```